# Angular: Repeatition in life cycle methods firing sequence

Tags: angular, lifecycle, cycle

Just executed a simple piece of code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function log(...args: Array<any>) {
  console.log.apply(null, args);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '',
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = 'Some value';

  ngAfterContentInit(arg: any) {
    log('ngAfterContentInit');
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked(arg: any) {
    log('ngAfterContentChecked');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(arg: any) {
    log('ngAfterViewInit');
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(arg: any) {
    log('ngAfterViewChecked');
  }

  ngDoCheck(arg: any) {
    log('ngDoCheck');
  }
}
```

Please, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xmjmb?file=src/app/app.component.ts
(StackBlitz is forever loading on compiling, don't know why. Do you see the same everlasting loading preview?)

And it resulted in Console in a sequence of messages: *ngDoCheck, ngAfterContentInit, ngAfterContentChecked, ngAfterViewInit, ngAfterViewChecked,*

-- Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode. --

*ngDoCheck*, **ngAfterContentChecked, ngAfterViewChecked**.

Why do we have again *ngAfterContentChecked* and *ngAfterViewChecked* after *ngDoCheck*? My suggestion is that the reason is that after *ngDoCheck* Angular again executed checks of *Content* and *View* (because *ngDoCheck* could do something to them). But then why wasn't *Content* check executed after *View* check whereas *ngAfterViewCheck* could do something to *Content*.

What is the logics behind this?

Comment: change selector: 'app-root' to 'my-app' in stackbitz

Comment: Thank you, Can Geylan!

Answer (score 1):

Your `index.html` file has the wrong selector.

Should be:

```html
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

Here it's working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hz5k5d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you! But still why do we have again ngAfterContentChecked and ngAfterViewChecked after ngDoCheck (they had already been fired before ngDoCheck)?

Comment: Angular always runs change detection twice.  ngDoCheck fires always. It is advisable to keep the implementation of Docheck simple and lightweight. Otherwise, it will result in bad user experience. In prod mode the change detection should happen just once per trigger (ApplicationRef#tick). In dev mode it should happen twice.